# Can't run ctest unless the test executable is named "tests"

Tags: cmake, ctest

I am trying to get CMake/CTest to work. My problem is that CTest does not seem to pick up a test executable unless it is named `tests`.

In my minimal example project I have a single CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(myproject C)
enable_testing()
set(TEST_EXE_NAME tests)
add_executable(${TEST_EXE_NAME} test_main.c)
add_test(NAME "My tests" COMMAND ${TEST_EXE_NAME})
```

...and a very simple test program,  `test_main.c`, that always passes:

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

I can run `make && make test`, and all is fine as long as `TEST_EXE_NAME` is set to `tests`. **However, when I change the executable name to something else, e.g. `mytests`, I get the following error:**

```
Could not find executable tests
Looked in the following places:
tests
tests
Release/tests
Release/tests
Debug/tests
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you recompile / re-make after changing the name? If not, Ctest will look for the new name, but the files are still name with the old one.

Comment: Yes, I do a full rm -rf ./* && cmake PATHTOSOURCE && make && make test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CMake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_test.html) for `add_test()` the test name may not contain spaces:

```
The test name may not contain spaces, quotes, or other
characters special in CMake syntax.
```

In the problematic example, the test was named "My tests". Changing the test name to "My_tests" solves the problem.

Apparently, the part of the test name after the space character (i.e. "tests") was interpreted as the test executable name.

Comment: Maybe similar but I had an executable called "testing" and was getting this error: ```ld: can't open output file for writing: testing, errno=21 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```

Changed the name and it worked fine.